# Using a search template in an ingest pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, data-ingestion, elasticsearch-template

Can an ElasticSearch ingest pipeline use a search template as its script?

Specifically, I'd like to configure an ingest pipeline so that whenever data of a particular type come in, we query ElasticSearch for some related data, and populate a field (or fields) on the original data based on the results, before loading it in.

I see that ingest pipelines can use scripts (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/script-processor.html), and that scripts can include search templates (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-using.html), but I haven't been able to find any information on potentially combining the two.

Comment: Are you asking whether during the ingest pipeline, you can perform a search (via a search template) and populate fields in the incoming document using results from the search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the feature you're asking for is coming in 7.5 via the new [enrich processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/ingest-enriching-data.html), which kind of provides index-time JOIN capability.

The main idea is to set up an [enrich policy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/enrich-setup.html#create-enrich-policy) that will source data from your related indexes into a new "enrich index" and then you can leverage that "enrich index" in your ingest pipeline using an [enrich processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/enrich-processor.html) in order to enrich your documents with related fields.

So, without going in too many details, here is how it works in practice:

1. You have an index `A` with fields (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) that you'd like to use for enriching your incoming documents
2. You define an enrich policy based on that index `A` and the "join" field `a`
3. You define an ingest pipeline with an enrich processor that will try to match field `z` of the incoming document against field `A.a` of the enrich index
4. If a match is found, your incoming document will get fields `b`, `c` and `d` from the index `A`. Note that it will also get the match field a that you can remove using a `remove` processor if needed.

That's pretty much what you expect. You can find a complete example [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/match-enrich-policy-type.html). At the beginning, it will work for exact matches (i.e. `term` query) and geo matches (i.e. `geo_shape` query), but they will probably add new kind of matches (like [`range` matches](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/48988)) in the near future.

Comment: That sounds great. But if something _changes_ in index `A`, will that trigger a re-enrichment / update of the matching document in the index that I am enriching?

Comment: What you can do in that case, if to reindex your data by applying the enrich pipeline and the new data will get picked up. So the answer is yes, but there's no guarantee about the timing, your mileage may vary depending on how you set this up, but it's definitely possible.

Comment: Elastic 7.5 has just been released: https://www.elastic.co/blog/elastic-stack-7-5-0-released

Answer (score 0):

So the `ingest script` pipeline is already the combination your looking for,
you should use the `if` option, read about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/script-processor.html).

Your pipeline should look something like this:

```
{
    "script": {
        "if": "ctx.type == 'thisType'",
        "source": """
                  //calculation here
                  ctx.newField = value;
                  """
    }
}
```

I recommend after you create your pipeline you test it using [simulate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/simulate-pipeline-api.html) as it will make your life much easier.

EDIT:

Thanks to @val that cleared up some confusion on my part.
So you can't really do exactly what you want however i recommend you read about [enrich](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest-enriching-data.html) pipeline. with some setup you might be able to make it happen.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is after. I think he wants to know whether while the document is transiting through the pipeline, a search query can be performed to populate the document to be indexed.