# join two seperate log files in logstash or elastic search to view in a single line in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, elk

I have two log files like this:
Log File 1:
page,pagedescription,pagetype

Log File 2:
page,userid,userpageaccess

The final output i want in kibana is single line:
page,userid,userpageaccess,pagedescription,pagetype

Basically a join on page column or a left outer join or merge on page column so that when i select fields from two log files i can see in one line, please guide if there is any solution in logstash or elasticsearch a small code snippet or explanation will solve

Comment: You can achieve what you need using an enrich index, as described in my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952346/using-a-search-template-in-an-ingest-pipeline/59047019#59047019

Comment: would like to do join without using x-pack feature

Comment: It's an XPack feature, but it's free and available with the Basic license.